# Upload of geojson to Mapbox studio showing strange artifacts

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I want to upload Geojson data to Mapbox studio. The upload works correctly, but the data in Mapbox show artifacts, which do not exist in the original data.
It seems that some vertex has a wrong position.

Please see a screenshot of the original data (in Qgis):
[image]

And this is the same section of the data in Mapbox Studio:
[image]

I tried using the Mapbox UI as well as the Mapbox cli: both datasets have artifacts, but different ones.

Original data: https://we.tl/t-vWHnewZ2TI